# iis server-unavailable! abc2 MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

We have faced an issue, which is "server-unavailable! abc2" pops up. Checked log file which methods are successfully called however it shows "server-unavailable! abc2"

[image]

Comment: That's not something IIS returns, so you need to dig into your web application in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

It caused by AWS ADC Health Check. Nothing related to IIS or or web application